# How can I click on Date and select yesterday with Cypress?

Tags: html, dom, click, cypress

I'm new with Cypress and DOm and I want to click on a Calendar and

```
  <div class="date-range"> 
  <date-picker change-handler.bind="datePickerStartDateChangeHandler" selected-date.bind="startDate" class="au-target" au-target-id="1118"> 
  <div class="date-picker"> <div click.delegate="toggleItems($event)" class="au-target selecteditem has-icon" au-target-id="53" style="outline: none;">
```

then click on Yesterdays Button

```
<div click.delegate="selectYesterday($event)" class="mp-btn mp-btn-secondary au-target" data-hook="datepicker-button" au-target-id="59">Yesterday</div>
```

I tried

```
cy.contains('[selected-date.bind="startDate"]').click()
cy.contains("Yesterday").click()
```

Comment: Looks like you're failing to close your quoted string: `"Yesterday).click()`

Comment: I fixed that, but the first click never happens.
```Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find content: '[selected-date.bind="startDate"]' but never did.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using this, not sure if this is best practice though.

```
cy.get('[au-target-id="1118"]').click()
cy.get('[au-target-id="59"]').click()
```